# Can't run unit test Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest, microsoft-fakes

When I try to run a specific test on Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, I have an error message : "Process with an Id of -1 is not running" (not sure of the translation, sorry).
And when I try to execute all the tests, the error message is "The specified file can't be found".

All my tests are detected, but none are executed. I've spent two days trying to make these tests work: recreating the test project, running the tested project under IISExpress instead of IIS, renaming the IISExpress folder in My Documents, forcing the compilation for x86 or x64, removing fakes assemblies, cleaning solution... nothing worked.

I use the built-in MSTest framework, and no specific framework is installed.

Here is the message I get in debug:

[image]

And here is what I get when I "only" execute:

[image]

English error messages:

```
------ Run test started ------
Process with an Id of -1 is not running.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00,1050004) ==========

------ Run test started ------
The system cannot find the file specified
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:05:16,7847051) ==========
```

Comment: I assume you're using the built in MSTest framework? If not (and maybe even if so), worth highlighting what unit test framework you are using (because e.g. NUnit, xUnit, etc can also be integrated into VS)

Comment: I use the built-in framework only, see my update.

Comment: Can you create, aside of your solution, a sample one, with just one test, in the simplest environment possible?

Comment: Same result - but I found exactly when each message is fired. When I try to debug the test (right click in the test method -> Debug test) I have "Process with an Id of -1 is not running", and when I execute the test via the test explorer I have "The specified file can't be found". Maybe Visual Studio is trying to attach to some process ?

Comment: @jessehouwing: see my edit. Nothing that could help I'm afraid :(
Maybe VS is trying to attach the website process ? anyway, I just tried under VS2013 Express, the tests are working until I try to use fakes... the error is not relative, but just in case, changing the version of the IDE doesn't help.

Comment: Yup: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8oe2pz2m3kabjxz/MvcApplication1.zip?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68662/discussion-between-gobes-and-jessehouwing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging Visual Studio itself it turns out that Visual Studio is trying to launch `vstest.executionengine.x86.exe`.

[image: Debugging Visual Studio itself]

Which doesn't exist in your instance of 2012:

[image: Files in that path]

### Solution

I repaired Visual Studio 2012 from the Programs and Features panel of Windows and that fixed the tests.
Upgrading it to Visual Studio 2012.4 seems to keep the tests in a running state. If you choose to repair 2012, make sure you also re-apply the latest update pack (Update 4), if you had an update installed.

Opening the project in Visual Studio 2013.4 or 2015 Preview also seems to work. So it seems that something has broken Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate somehow and repairing it resolves the issue.

Comment: W00t \o/

Thank you so much, the tests are working after a repair and a reboot!